# How to update a sheet with Pyton(Gspread) with one api call?

Tags: python, gspread

I have 2 google sheet files. The first one has information that I have to pull out depending on certain criteria's which are irrelevant for the question. That I have done. The data contains names as well as hours not supported. I have created objects with those values and put them in a list. The length of the list is 137. Lets call this list "hours_not_supported".

The second sheet file has predefined variables from A1:A B1:B C1:C which contain names, sir names, emails. On the far right of the excel file there is a header called hours not supported. The length of those rows is 170.

Now since hours_not_supported list is smaller then the amount of rows(137 to 170) in the second sheet file, that means that the second sheet file has people that have no data to be filled since they do not exist in the first excel file.

What I have to do, is if the name of the object in the list "hours_not_supported" matches A1:A name, so basically something along the lines of if A1:A == object.name I have to put in the object.hours in the far left of the sheet file on one of the rows, in other words update the sheet. I can do that with a loop and some if statements, the problem is the 429 error with the call limit, I would error out.

So what I wanted to ask is how should I proceed? the update() and batch_update() functions are the only ones that I saw that only use 1 API call. The problem is that those functions can't identify if lets say A1s name is equal to any of the names within the list of objects. Also, I am not allowed to use the function sleep.

Any ideas? Would love to write what have I tried as far as coding goes, but for this issue specifically there isn't anything to write since I mentioned I can't use loops cause of 429 error and those functions don't filter out which name is which.

Comment: You specifically said "Excel".  Are these Excel .xlsx files, or are these Google Sheets files?

Comment: My bad, they are google sheet files, sorry for that. I have edited it